# CSS - grab elements and display them inline (absolute positioning?)

Tags: css, position, inline, absolute

I have a webpage full of DOM elements, and I want to take all h3s out of that page and display them inline next to each other at the top of the page. The question is - is that even possible?

```
<h3>I want</h3>
    There are tons of other content between them so...
<h3>These headers</h3>
    Keep in mind the're separated by many DOM elements...
<h3>To be displayed</h3>
    Luckily no other h3s between them...
<h3>Inline next to</h3>
    Thank you for trying to help :)
<h3>Each other </h3>
```

Here's jsfiddle where I tried to use absolute positioning, but I'm pretty sure it's gonna be hard to take this way (margins):

http://jsfiddle.net/zLbuP/

I need the code to be **working at least for IE7** and above and **I cannot use any JS/jQuery** (it will be rather easy to do with jQuery though). Of course **I cannot edit the html itself too**.

Any ideas, or impossiblu? ;)

Comment: so there is a text between h3 elements that is not in paragraph or any other element?

Comment: Actually, not only text, there's everything from images, spans, inputs, textareas, upload fields and more. I just simplified it a bit.

Comment: There is a solution using :nth-child() but it won't be supported in the lower versions of IE. http://jsfiddle.net/zLbuP/2/

Comment: @luke2012 I think you could post that solution as an answer

Comment: Why can't you use JS? This is a problem I wouldn't attempt to solve with CSS, for the browser compatibility issues mentioned above. If you coded it using @luke2012 solution, then have a JS backup that could be a feasible solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to do with jQuery/Javascript?

I just messed around a bit and came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/zLbuP/19/

The code just gets the content from all the H3's, removes them and creates a new, combined H3.

```
//When then DOM is ready
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //Cache the content of the headings to a variable so it may be removed before creating a new H3
    //this allows us to select the new H3 without having to use more complex selectors
    var h3text = $('#WhatIHaveNow h3').text();
    // remove the old H3's now that we have their content
    $('#WhatIHaveNow h3').remove();
    // create a new, empty H3 at the top of the parent div
    $('#WhatIHaveNow').prepend("<h3></h3>");
    //insert our cached content
    $('#WhatIHaveNow h3').text(h3text);

});
```

Comment: This could be tweaked to insert a space after each string or you could just make sure the you have a space at the end (inside) the H3's in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't avoid using JS. You can set all `h3` tags to an absolute position and have them all at the top but you need to use JQuery to set their margin. I have made a small script to set the margin dynamically for each `h3` tag, based on the width of the previous sibling:

```
var margin = 0;
$("#TryMe h3").each(function () {
    margin += $(this).prev().width();
    $(this).css("margin-left", margin + "px")
    margin += 20;
});
```

You can see a live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/VezCA/2/

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use nth-child; i.e.

```
h3 { position:absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; }
h3:nth-child(1) { margin-top: 15px; } 
h3:nth-child(2) { margin-top: 30px; }
```

IE7 doesn't support nth-child, though, and it's pretty hackish even if you could get it to work how you wanted it. As others have said, it's easy to do in jQuery or plain JS.